# Перебор массива объектов с удалением повторяющейся даты и аккумулированием счетчика

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов :

```
const dates = [
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 0},
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 5},
{date: "2020-08-14", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-14", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-16", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-16", counter: 0},
{date: "2020-08-17", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-17", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 1},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 1},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 1},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 1},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2}]
```

В итоге должен получиться массив без повторяющихся дней и просуммированным показателем counter для каждого дня.
Например:

```
newDates = [
{date: '2020-08-12', counter: 11,},
{date: '2020-08-14', counter: 4},
....
]
```

Пробовал вот так:

```
uniqueArr = []

for (let i = 1; i <= dates.length; i++) {
      if (dates[i].date === dates[i-1].date) {
        let date = dates[i-1].date
        let uniqCounter = dates[i].counter + dates[i-1].counter
        uniqueArr.push({uniqCounter, date})

      }
    }
```

Но получается совсем не то, что нужно, даже не понимаю в какую сторону думать.

Comment: Это кому задание?

Comment: Мне ;)
Не могу понять с какой стороны подступиться к проблеме, пробовал разными методами перебирать массив, но никак не выходит

Comment: "пробовал разными методами перебирать массив" - где?

Comment: Код не приводил, потому что получались нерабочие велосипеды. Но алгоритм был следующий - брать соседние элементы массива, сравнивать у них даты - если сходится - суммировать counter

Comment: Я не буду писать решение, пока не увижу Ваш вариант.

Comment: Добавил вариант через for в вопрос. Пытался еще через forEach и reduce, но там совсем стыдные варианты получаются.  Самая большая трудность это то, что каждый элемент это объект. Не понимаю как сообщить скрипту что нужно смотреть на предыдущий элемент в массиве, сравнить их даты и если всё окей - складывать counter и пушить в итоговый результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const dates = [
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 0},
{date: "2020-08-12", counter: 5},
{date: "2020-08-14", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-14", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-16", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-16", counter: 0},
{date: "2020-08-17", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-17", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 1},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 1},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 1},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 1},
{date: "2020-08-18", counter: 2}
];

let newDates = [];
let lookup = {};
dates.forEach(i => lookup[i.date] = (lookup[i.date] || 0) + i.counter);
Object.keys(lookup).forEach(i => newDates.push({date: i, counter: lookup[i]}));
console.log(newDates);
```

Comment: Вау..спасибо большое, буду разбираться в этом решении